# Java arraylist initialization in a constructor or method

Tags: java, arraylist

I was trying to initialize an ArrayList in a constructor, and I have something like this:

```
public class A {

private ArrayList<Items> _items = null;
private ArrayList<Items> _collection = null;

public A(int size1, int size2) { 
    this._items = new ArrayList<Items>(size1 * size2);
}

public void create(int size) {
    this._collection = new ArrayList<Items>(size);
}
```

But when I tried to add something to the _items ArrayList, I was getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Could you explain this, please? I was searching for it and added `this._items`instead of `_items`. I thought I going out of borders, but I tried to print `_items.size` and was getting `0`, instead of `size1 * size2`...

I left the `ArrayList = null` because the size depends on the size1/size2 coming from the constructor

Comment: Can you post the code on how did you try to add to list?

Comment: `But when I tried to add something to the _items ArrayList, I was getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` could you show us how you ware trying to add something to your list?

Comment: As @Steve P. said, I was adding with a specific Index. Like:
`this._items.add(index, Item)`
Since there was nothing in the ArrayList, size would be 0 and I was getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Simply search in Google, "*`ArrayList` in java.*" I'm quite sure that you yourself will be able to find it very simple within no time and solve the problem in question yourself :)

Comment: Well, I actually have the Java documentations opened, and when I wrote the program, I was looking for the methods I could use with an ArrayList...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source from `ArrayList`:

The constructor:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) 
{
     super();

     if (initialCapacity < 0)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);
     this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

You called `add(int, E)`:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
     rangeCheckForAdd(index);
     ensureCapacity(size+1);  // Increments modCount!!
     System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1, size - index);
     elementData[index] = element;
     size++;
 }
```

`add` calls `rangeCheckForAdd(int)`:

```
 private void rangeCheckForAdd(int index) {
     if (index > size || index < 0)
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
 }
```

It may be subtle, but when you called the constructor, despite initializing an `Object[]`, you did not initialize `size`.  Hence, from `rangeCheckForAdd`, you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `size` is 0.

All you did by passing the argument to the constructor was set the capacity, which sets the size of the array that backs the `ArrayList`.

Instead of using `add(int, E)`, you can use `add(E e)` and this won't occur.

Comment: So, how should I inicialize it?
`this._items = new ArrayList(size1*size2)` ?

Comment: @msk Your initialization is fine.  You don't want to use the raw type as in the comment you just made.  You are just unable to use `set()` unless there is already an element in the location.  You can use the `add` method as I suggested, ie `_items.add(myItem)`.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. I had an algorithm that was adding in specific locations, so I wouldnt need to go through all the array to find a specific Item. I can't do that, can I?

Comment: @msk I assume that you're using the `set` method to try to add elements.  The issue is that the way `ArrayList` is implemented, you can't use `set` unless an object is already in that location.  To initially populate the `ArrayList`, you can simply use the `add` method, which will add your object to the current index, where index starts at 0 and increments each time you add to the list, but that's all handled for you in the background.

Comment: @msk If after you've added elements to the `ArrayList`, and you know that the element that you want is at index 2, the you could simply call the `get(2)` to retrieve the element or `set(2, myItem)` to replace it.

Comment: I was looking for it and I wasn't using `set(int index, E element)`. I was using `add(int index, E element)` .

Comment: I had a function
`int getPosition(Item e)` and would return an index, depending on the item given to it.
I was using `this._items.add(getPosition(item), item)`

Comment: @msk it seems like you're trying to find an item in the list, not add it (if that's not the case, `getPosition` is a poor name).  If you're trying to find an item, you are in fact going to have to iterate through the list.

Comment: This was supposed to be kind of a matrix, and each item would have its own position. `getPosition` was an algorithm I created to calculate the position in the ArrayList, depending on the items' coordinates on that matrix. ArrayList might not be the best solution, but I actually have to use it. And I was not trying to use the `set`. 
Like I said before, I was using the `add` method, the one I can give an index and will add in a speficic location. But the way you speak, I think it will have the same problem as the `set` function

Comment: I was going through the Java documentation about the ArrayList and I got it. The add function has the same problem. I will fill the ArrayList with `0`value and will add later. Thanks for the help and sorry for asking some stupid questions..

Answer (score 0):

You should read the javadocs for this. size is not about 'how much the list can store' but about 'how many objects is it holding when the size was called'.

Since Lists (and for that matter any collection) are designed to grow dynamically with data being put into them, so it makes no sense to ask for the capacity of the list. If you are interested in capacity related introspection you should work with arrays instead.

Lists follow simple philosophical operations add an object, get an object, remove an object and iterate over all objects.